# How to set Scroll View visibility programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 *Buttons*, 3 *Scroll Views*, and some *Textviews* and pictures and what not.

The 3 *Buttons* I want to be able to show a different *Scroll View* when they are clicked.

So clicking *Button #1* would **show** *Scroll View #1* and hide *Scroll View #2 & #3*

etc....

Is there a way to do this programmatically? Like in an OnClick() Event?

Comment: You can set tags on buttons and scrollviews. So on button click, you get its tag, and compare with scrollviews if equals then show it, if not set its visibility gone. That's it i guess.

Comment: if my answer is helpful to u dont forget to upvote me

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `setVisiblility()` method:

```
mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

by setting `View.GONE` you'll view will become invisible, and will not take any actual space inside the layout container it reside in.

then when you'll want to make it visible again, use the:

```
mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ExpandableListview** For that

Refer this Links this will help to Implement ExpandableListview in android

1. http://androidword.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-expandablelistview.html
2. http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html
3. http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html